# GloVe Tweet Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, word2vec

Good day. I am beginner in Python.

I have created short machine learning code with the use of Word2Vec model that analyses tweets and categorize them into one of the three categories.

Now I have to recreate this code with use of alternatives to Word2Vec model.

I have been trying to utilize GloVe, however I cannot figure out how to do this.

Can this be achieved with just Glove?

Are there any simpler alternatives I could use?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Yes. You can use GLoVe to train word-vectors from the same corpus instead. Then, you can use those word-vectors instead however you were using word2vec-derived vectors. But, why? GLoVe vectors trained from the same texts will likely perform very much like word2vec vectors. (They both result in a vector-per word, based on roughly the same input data.) Have you tried any other text-classification algorithms?

Comment: No i haven't tried any other text-classification algorithms. What should I try?

Comment: If you're just starting out, find some text-classification tutorials which seem clear & applied to similar datasets, & try any methods they demonstrate. It's traditional to start with a simple "bag of words" representation, then compare one or more alternate classification-algorithms. Starting in Python's popular `scikit-learn`, working through its <https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html>, reviewing its 'cheat sheet' <https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html>, & looking at other intros/surveys-of-methods all help.